# Salesforce standard mouse over functionality On vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I need to implement on Visualforce page. For example i have
Agent Object    it contain the fields AentID and Name , Phone..
So in VisualforcePage I am displaying Agent ID . if i mouse over on Agent Id .. Need to dispaly Agent Name and phone Like below Image..

Pleas guide me if you have any Idea..[image]

Answer (score 2):

Having your record ID and Name, you can easily bring the mini page layout:

```
<a id="{!account.Id}"
    onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!account.Id}', '/{!account.Id}/m?retURL={!account.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
    onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!account.Id}').hide();"
    onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!account.Id}', '/{!account.Id}/m?retURL={!account.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
    onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!account.Id}').hide();"
    href="/{!account.Id}"> 
    {!account.Name}
</a>
```

*Replace 'account' with your agent record variable.*

The fields that appear in the mini page layout can be configured by navigating to the object's page layout, click edit and then click in the top right corner on "Mini Page Layout".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. can you plz go through below link so you can come to know exact requirment...    https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BCcUIAW